# GNUPLOT - How to check if "multiplot" is set

Tags: gnuplot

If a script breaks in the middle of a multiplot sequence gnuplot is left in multiplot mode.
Before being able to re-run the script I need to manually put it back to normal mode or it will fail if I change terminal:

Example:

```
gnuplot> load "script.gnuplot"     
         "script.gnuplot", line 35: warning: Cannot find or open file "inputDataFile.dat"
         "script.gnuplot", line 35: No data in plot

multiplot> load "script.gnuplot"

multiplot> set term wxt 666
                    ^
           "script.gnuplot", line 30: You can't change the terminal in multiplot mode

multiplot> unset multiplot                                                           
gnuplot>
```

Is there a variable that is set when in multiplot mode? A check at the beginning of the script could then be executed and, in case, multiplot mode disable. Alternative solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, after I wrote down the question I just realized I could stick a

```
unset multiplot
```

at the beginning of the script.

No warnings if the multiplot mode is not set so it does the job neately.